# Mutual client authentication with PKCS#11

Tags: android, ssl, pkcs#11

I am trying to create a browser application that will access a server which requires TLS Mutual Client Authentication. The application needs to be able to supply the client certificate and key via a PKCS#11 interface.

Having looked at various articles on mutual tls for Android, I believe the PKCS#11 requirement rules out using the Android KeyChain/adding the certificates to the default keystore on Android (because the private key cannot be directly accessed).

I have the PKCS#11 interface working so I can use the private key to sign data.

Is there a way to intercept the calls for Android to sign data with a key so that I can use the PKCS#11 interface instead? Currently it seems that my only option really is to implement my own TLS stack to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends :) What platform(s) are you targeting? On Jelly Bean, there is some support for hardware devices in the keystore, so you can write a keymaster module that uses your PKCS#11. That, however is a OS component, so it would require implementing your own ROM. You can also develop your own JCE provider that is backed by the PKCS#11 module. Then, in your browser, make sure the SSL engine uses your provider when doing client auth.

Comment: Very interesting. Does this imply that there is a way to use "non-native" keys in JB? Too bad I don't have a device with this version.

Do you have pointers?

Comment: @martin What do you mean by 'non-native'? The default keymaster implementation is done in software (OpenSSL), if the hardware supports crypto operations, there are modules that use them.

Comment: Native as "present in Android keychains and used by Android platform calls", much like CryptoAPI on Windows. What I mean, is there a way to create a CSP/Minidriver thing for Android, which could use keys that reside either on a network server, a smart card or some other weird token.

Comment: Technically, yes. The API is now part of the platform, so as long as you can generate keys and sign/verify, it should be doable. Here's my writeup on how this is done for the Galaxy Nexus using a TEE trusted application (it is not enabled in production builds yet, however): http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/07/jelly-bean-hardware-backed-credential.html