# Two-way SSL without access to client private key (but able to sign)

Tags: java, android, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, two-way

**Summary**
I need to establish a two-way SSL connection (with client certificate) in Android, preferrably using Apache HttpClient. I have access to the client's certificate, but no direct access to the clients private key. I can, however sign data with the client's private key.

Since I can't create a normal keystore without the private key, is there some way to override the SSL handshake and manually sign the challenge sent by the server?

**What? You have no key, but you can still use it to sign?**
The user's private key is stored on a dedicated hardware device. It will present the user's public certificate, and it allows me to pass in data that it will then sign/encrypt with the private key. But it will not give me the key itself.

Comment: What you're describing is perfectly possible in plain Java using a PKCS#11 keystore for example. I'm not familiar with this on Android, but is there something mentioned about this in your hardware token documentation?

Comment: PKCS#11 seems like the way to go. I'll scan through the documentation for the hardware token to see where to start, I guess.

Comment: You don't have to do anything except configure Java to use the PKCS#11 keystore. JSSE will do the rest.

Comment: Don't I need to link to the vendor's PKCS#11 implementation as well, to get it working?

Comment: Generally yes. On the Oracle JRE, the SunPKCS11 provider expects to be pointed to a DLL/SO implementing the PKCS#11 interface: that library is normally provided by the token vendor (or projects like OpenSC). You might not have that on your Android device. Of course, you probably won't have the SunPKCS11 provider anyway. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11641912/372643) and related comments (including [this article](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/07/jelly-bean-hardware-backed-credential.html)) should be of interest.

Comment: Indeed, the SunPKCS11 provider is not available, but I do have the SO file containing the vendor implementation. So it seems I need to find or develop an Android replacement for Sun's PKCS#11 provider? This turns out to be more tricky than I hoped for...